# Material ui textfield ith redux form issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

i'm having an issue here which i can't handle
I have a textfield which i made compatible with redux form
like this:

```
const renderTextField = props => (
  <TextField {...props} />
);
```

and i'm using it like this:

```
<Field
          id="searchCif"
          name="searchCif"
          component={renderTextField}
          floatingLabelText={SEARCHVIEW_HINT_CIF}
          floatingLabelFixed={false}
          value
        />
```

Then i writing this in my container:

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';
import SearchDefaultView from './views/searchDefaultView';

import { requestCustomerInfo } from './actions/customerActions';

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    requestCustomerInfo: formData =>
      dispatch(requestCustomerInfo(formData))
  }
);

const SearchDefaultReduxForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'customerInfo',  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SearchDefaultView);

const SearchDefaultContainer = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchDefaultReduxForm);

export default SearchDefaultContainer;
```

But when i'm writing the value and submit my form the form has NO VALUES. what am i missing?

From the dicumentation i used this:

```
const renderTextField = ({
                           input,
                           label,
                           meta: { touched, error },
                           ...custom
                         }) =>
  <TextField
    hintText={label}
    floatingLabelText={label}
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />

const SearchDefaultView = (props) => {
  const { requestCustomerInfo, handleSubmit } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(requestCustomerInfo)}>
      <Menu
        autoWidth={false}
        style={styleSearchMenu}
      >
        <Divider />
        <Field
          id="searchCif"
          name="searchCif"
          component={renderTextField}
          floatingLabelText={SEARCHVIEW_HINT_CIF}
          floatingLabelFixed={false}
        />
        <br />
        <Field
          id="searchAFM"
          name="searchAFM"
          component={renderTextField}
          floatingLabelText={SEARCHVIEW_HINT_AFM}
          floatingLabelFixed={false}
        />
        <br />
        <RaisedButton
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          primary
          label={SEARCHVIEW_SEARCH}
        />
      </Menu>
    </form>
  );
};
```

But it is showing me an error in compilation at ...custom

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use a custom field for Redux-Form, Redux-form gives you access to both props like `onChange` etc, **but also other meta-data** (like if the form has been touched or not). These different kinds of **props are grouped depending on type**. The interesting part for you is that all the attributes associated with a normal input element (like `onChange`, `value`, `type`) are grouped in `props.input`. So to pass *those* down to the `<TextField />` component you can't use the spread operator (`...` ) on `props` directly. You must use it on `props.input`.

```js
const renderTextField = props => (
  <TextField {...props.input} />
);
```

You may also have to deal with the fact that the `onChange` method that `<TextField />` expects doesn't necessarily have the same signature as the `onChange` method that Redux-form provides you. So you may have to do some manual work to make them work together, similar to what I've [outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139097/reduxform-getting-select-value-from-semantic-ui-select-input/46139684#46139684). You'd have to read up on the documentation of both the `onChange` of Redux-Form and Material-UI TextField respectively.

You may also be interested to know that for `material-ui` components, there actually already exists a [library that has done that manual work for you: `redux-form-material-ui`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback but erikras in his documentation for material UI is not using props.input. It seems like my state is not updated

Comment: From what I can see, he does. See the link. He destructures the method arguments and picks out the input part and spreads it. https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/material-ui/

Comment: The renderTextfield is not compiling. It crushes at ...custom. You can check it yourself

Comment: What code isnt compiling? The one in my example? The one in the documentation? You may have to update the question with your current code. It's too unclear what your current situation is.

Comment: I edit the renderTextField with the one in the documentation but it's not compiling

Comment: Ok, but you realize that it's more probable that your code is wrong, than that the documentation code is wrong? I would have to see how you copied it. Note that the docs are using a const, not a function like you had before. That could be it. Or any number of other things. If you Don't show me your updated code I can't help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the updated code. I don't see anything wrong with it, and I've managed to make it work in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/0twjzL20/2/ (Look at line 39 where the `renderTextField`is used)

Comment: And what happens if you remove just the parts with `...custom`? (both in the function arguments and when you spread them on your TextField).

Comment: Maybe also paste the whole error message. Since you say you have used `...` for objects before, and since the JSFiddle works with the code, that suggests that the issue is something other than the method copied from the docs.

Comment: I can't because the words are many. The error is the below i've type without info about my file.

Comment: If it's too big for the comments you can post it in the answer. The error messages aren't always exact. Try looking for other small errors. Maybe you need to add  `(  );` around the JSX you return from `renderTextField.` Maybe you still have your old `renderTextField` function in the code so that it is colliding with the new one.

Comment: Please listen to me this is not the case of my problem. I cant add text to the text field. It seems like my input is not working

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, then nothing works. That's why I'm trying to solve the error. What have I missed?

Comment: The custom spread is useless in my case. The input is what i need so i removed it. The problem is i cant type text in the field

Comment: It's not useless, it's what sends your `floatingLabelText` prop on the `<Field />`  down to your `<TextField />`.

Comment: In your original code, you used the prop `value` on `<Field value />`   (which I think is wrong), so that could be the problem if you have gone back to your original code. Because then the value would never be updated.

Comment: Also i have user the form reducer properly

Comment: Have you checked that the form works without using Material-UI? I think you would almost have to start a new question, because it's too unclear what your code currently looks like. I've provided a link that shows that the code from the documentation works. It just doesn't work in **your** code. So you probably have more than one issue, which makes it's very complex to solve, especially when you provide so little feedback. It's still not clear if you even tried the solution in my answer. (which also works..but maybe not in your code.  see lines 15 + 29. https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/0twjzL20/4/)

Comment: Ok, that's strange. There could possibly be an issue with you using another version of Material UI than in the docs. Do you know what version you have? (It should say in your package.json file)

Comment: "redux-form-material-ui": "^4.2.0",

Comment: If you use **redux-form**-material-ui you shouldn't have to make a special method at all. Because **redux-form**-material-ui, like I mentioned in my answer,  has done the work for you (the work that the custom method does). It should work just to import it like this: `import {TextField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';`  and then pass the imported`TextField` component directly to your `Field`, like this: <Field component={TextField} />  (and pass the other props you want as well (the label etc).  They have examples here https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the onChange prop of the component.

onChange: Callback function that is fired when the textfield's value changes.

You should dispatch the change and update the data in redux container.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

Comment: The value propery is wrong. Remove It or attach It to the variable in redux

Comment: I cannot understand what you are saying. The value is attached automatically by redux form. Tha'ts the case of using it

Comment: <Field           id="searchCif"           name="searchCif"           component={renderTextField}           floatingLabelText={SEARCHVIEW_HINT_CIF}           floatingLabelFixed={false}           value         />

Comment: Value is  assigned to nothing, even if you are passing props above from redux.